# Filter JS issues

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, nativescript-vue

I want to filter on the input and then show a different result. 
But like you can see in the console.log output it change my `this.data.stationInfo.stations` array. 
Filter should create a new array and not change my array that is what I read from the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I think the problem is with the usage of `this`? Anyone a idea how to solve it?

```
onTextChanged: function () {
            let copy = this.data.stationInfo.stations;
            console.log("this.data.stationInfo.stations.length", this.data.stationInfo.stations.length);
            copy  = copy
                .filter(el => {
                    return el.eng站名.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.data.searchBar.search.toLowerCase())
                    ||
                        el.站名.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.data.searchBar.search.toLowerCase())
                    ||
                        el.traWebsiteCode.startsWith(this.data.searchBar.search.toLowerCase())
                });
            this.data.resultDetails.stations = copy;
            console.log("copy.length", copy.length);
            console.log("after copy.length this.data.stationInfo.stations.length", this.data.stationInfo.stations.length);
        },
```

console.log output:

> JS: 'this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 239
>
> JS: 'copy.length' 4
>
> JS: 'after copy.length this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 4
>
> JS: 'this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 4
>
> JS: 'copy.length' 0
>
> JS: 'after copy.length this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 0
>
> JS: 'this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 0
>
> JS: 'copy.length' 0
>
> JS: 'after copy.length this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 0
>
> JS: 'this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 0
>
> JS: 'copy.length' 0
>
> JS: 'after copy.length this.data.stationInfo.stations.length' 0

UPDATE:

NativeScript PlayGround: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=1SXSNW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not create references. Actually you a setting a reference to your original array and then all mutations against you copy will be reflected on original array.

```
onTextChanged: function () {
            console.log("this.data.stationInfo.stations.length", this.data.stationInfo.stations.length);
            let newArray  = this.data.stationInfo.stations
                .filter(el => {
                    return el.eng站名.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.data.searchBar.search.toLowerCase())
                    ||
                        el.站名.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.data.searchBar.search.toLowerCase())
                    ||
                        el.traWebsiteCode.startsWith(this.data.searchBar.search.toLowerCase())
                });
            this.data.resultDetails.stations = newArray;
            console.log("copy.length", copy.length);
            console.log("after copy.length this.data.stationInfo.stations.length", this.data.stationInfo.stations.length);
        }
```

Also I would advise you to improve your code and to do all needed stuff in one place. You can iterate over array and directly exclude all needed stations. Here an example:

```
onTextChanged: function () {
const stations = this.data.stationInfo.stations;
function doSearch(el,str) {
    return 
        el.eng站名.toLowerCase().startsWith(str) ||
        el.站名.toLowerCase().startsWith(str) ||
        el.traWebsiteCode.startsWith(str);
}

for(let j=0; j < stations.length; j++){
    if(!doSearch(stations[j], this.data.searchBar.search.toLowerCase())){
        stations.splice(j, 1);
    }
}

console.log(stations);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, I need to assign stations to the variable `this.data.resultDetails.stations = stations;` but when I try again. What I mean with that is delete the input and typo in another word the length of `this.data.stationInfo.stations` is not original anymore see the console.log output

Comment: In this case please create a working example and I will help, because right now, from my point of view, it should work correctly.

Comment: so, you want to do autocomplete?

Comment: So you should not use `this.data.stationInfo.stations` here `for="item in data.resultDetails.stations"`. My suggestion is to create a copy of it on the level above, smth like `filteredStations` and use this variable in your html template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195331/discussion-between-dganenco-and-steven).